# searching through the whole website rather than a group of products

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, search

I have a search controller which gets Searchid and keywordSearch to show the search results. for example, user can search for iPhone in mobile category. I am trying to make the search happen for any keyword (KeywordSearch) in all product groups (Searchid) and I need help doing that.

The HTML code:

```
<div class="top_search_form">

@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "search_form clearfix", @id = "frm_topsearch" }))
{
    <div id="search_box">
        <select name='Searchid' style="margin-left:1px;">
            @foreach (var item1 in repsearch.GetGroup())
            {
                <option value='@item1.Group_ID'>@item1.Group_Name</option>
            }

        </select>


        <input type="text" placeholder="search" name='keywordSearch'>

        <input type="submit" class="fa fa-search" style="margin-right: 1px;width:38px !important;background-color: #CC456B !important;height: 34px !important;" name="name" value="search" />


    </div>

    <div id="search_result_box">

    </div><!-- end search_result_box -->
}
```

The controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Search(int Searchid, string keywordSearch)
    {
        var qid = db.Tbl_Group.Where(a => a.Group_ID == Searchid).FirstOrDefault();

        if (qid == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            if (keywordSearch == "" || keywordSearch == null)
            {
                var q = db.Tbl_Product.Where(a => a.Product_Groupid == Searchid).ToList();

                if (q == null)
                {
                    ViewBag.State = "Error";
                    ViewBag.Key = keywordSearch;
                    ViewBag.Groupid = Searchid;
                    return View();
                }
                else
                {

                    ViewBag.State = "Ok";
                    ViewBag.Key = keywordSearch;
                    ViewBag.Groupid = Searchid;
                    return View(q);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var search = (from a in db.Tbl_Product where a.Product_Groupid == Searchid && a.Product_Name.Contains(keywordSearch) select a).ToList();

                if (search == null)
                {
                    ViewBag.State = "Error";
                    ViewBag.Key = keywordSearch;
                    ViewBag.Groupid = Searchid;
                    return View();

                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.State = "Error";
                    ViewBag.Key = keywordSearch;
                    ViewBag.Groupid = Searchid;
                    return View(search);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I think indexing(lucene or solr etc) would be a better approach for a full text search. These technologies are flat so they are easier and quicker to search. Even if you build a db query that loops through all columns looking for a keyword match it will be extremely slow. I hope that helps

Comment: could you recommend a source for learning lucene or solr?